# android - play background music

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing a game in android using Eclipse,
I want to control the music across all activities and pause, play or change it on each activity,

How Can I do this? Searching showed me using services maybe will not be a good way.

i used

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.m_tp);
```

but it wont work as i want.

Comment: Please show us what did you try ?

Comment: You must need to use service, for run music in background,Also you can control it from any activity or fragment.